# Able to run Java code using Code Runner but not CLI

Tags: java, vscode-code-runner, coderunner

Currently a beginner to `Java` and I have the extension `Code Runner` installed. I am able to run my code within the window via the `Run | Debug` options provided by `Code Runner`. However, after compiling the file with `javac`, I am unable to run the file. This is the basic code inside a filepath `CommandLineApp/HelloWorld.java`.

```
package CommandLineApp;
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world..!!!");
    }    
}
```

After I `cd` into CommandLineApp, I ran

```
javac HelloWorld.java
java HelloWorld
```

which gives me this error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CommandLineApp/HelloWorld (wrong name: HelloWorld)
```

Apologies if this is a really simple question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't `cd` to the package directory, i.e. `CommandLineApp`. You `cd` to the parent directory of the package directory. And you give the fully qualified name when you launch the class, i.e:

```
java CommandLineApp.HelloWorld
```

Alternatively, you use the `-classpath` option in the `java` command, i.e:

```
java -cp dir CommandLineApp.HelloWorld
```

where `dir` is the path to the parent directory of `CommandLineApp`.

Perhaps this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html) will help.

Note that, since JDK 11, you can also launch a Java source code file. Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html).

By the way, according to Java [naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html), the package name should be something like `commandlineapp` or `commandline.app`

Comment: Thank you so much! I was following a tutorial that glossed over this and used a Code Runner, but I missed the part where he was not CD into the folder. Really appreciate entertaining such a basic question!